# Operation has timed out using powershell script

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, user-profile-service

Hi I am running a powershell script to update the custom user profile property called 'testvalue' whose values are [2,3] format. We have total of 20,000 users but at 2300 th user the powershell script threw an error below

```
Error: : Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "The operation has timed out"
```

**Below is the script**

```
#Importing PowerShell Module
    Import-Module Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell -DisableNameChecking


#Authenticating User to SharePoint Online
   $username = "firsttName.lastname@siteoffice.com" 
   $Adminurl = "https://siteoffice-admin.sharepoint.com"
   $siteColUrl = "https://siteoffice.sharepoint.com"

#Logging Method for errors
   $DATE = get-date
   $LogPath = "C:\Work\UpdateUserProfile"
   $LogFileName = "LogFileName.log"

$FilePath = $LogPath +"\" + $LogFileName
$logFileCreated = $False
function write-log([string]$label, [string]$logMsg)
{ 

    if($logFileCreated -eq $False)
    {
        write-host "Creating log file..."
        if((Test-Path -path $LogPath) -ne $True)
        {
            write-host"Provide proper values to LogPath folder" -ForegroundColor Red
        }
        else
        {
            Add-Content -Path $FilePath -Value $logHeader
            $script:logFileCreated  = $True
            write-host "Log file created..."
            [string]$info = [System.String]::Format("[$Date] {0}: {1}",$label, $logMsg)
            Add-Content -Path $FilePath -Value $info
        }
    }
    else
    {
        [string]$info = [System.String]::Format("[$Date] {0}: {1}",$label, $logMsg)
        Add-Content -Path $FilePath -Value $info
    }
 }

try
 {
   Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
   Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UserProfiles.dll"
   Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
   Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UserProfiles.dll"


   #Bind to site collection
   $password = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter password" -AsSecureString 
   $Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($Adminurl)

   $Creds = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username,$Password)
   $Context.Credentials = $Creds
   Write-Host "Successfully connected.." -ForegroundColor Green
   $ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteColUrl)
   $Creds = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username,$Password)
   $ctx.Credentials = $Creds


   #Retrieve lists
   $web = $ctx.Web
   $Users = $ctx.Web.SiteUsers
    $list = $ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Test")
   $query = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery]::CreateAllItemsQuery()
   $items = $list.GetItems($query)
   $ctx.Load($items)
   $ctx.Load($Users)
   $ctx.Load($web)
   $ctx.Load($List)
   $ctx.ExecuteQuery()


   $PeopleManager = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UserProfiles.PeopleManager($Context)

   foreach($item in $items)
  { 
   Foreach ($User in $Users)
    {  
      $UserNameValue =  $User.LoginName
      #write-Host $UserNameValue -ForegroundColor  Red 
      $UserProfile = $PeopleManager.GetPropertiesFor($UserNameValue)
      $context.Load($UserProfile)
      $Context.ExecuteQuery()
      $ToolVal = $UserProfile.UserProfileProperties.Testvalue
     $PeopleManager.SetSingleValueProfileProperty($UserProfile.AccountName, "Testvalue", "[2,3]")
        $context.ExecuteQuery() 

      }
  }  
} 
  catch
       { 
          write-host"Error: " $_.Exception.Message
       }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out by setting the `RequestTimeOut` property of Context to millisecond

```
$context.RequestTimeOut = 5000*10000
```

Answer (score 1):

**STEP 1**
Click the "Start" button from the desktop and then click the "All Programs" option.

**STEP 2**
Click the "Accessories" option and then click the "Windows PowerShell" option. The PowerShell program launches on your screen.

**STEP 3**
Enter "Dir WSMan:\localhost\shell" into the command line and then press the "Enter" key on your keyboard.

**STEP 4**
View the list of configuration settings and look for the "IdleTimeout" field.

**STEP 5**
Enter "Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\shell\IdleTimeout" into the command line, and then press the "spacebar" key.

**STEP 6**
Enter the number, in milliseconds, that determines how long a session is disconnected before it is disregarded.

**STEP 7**
Press the "Enter" key and then the new timeout setting is configured.

Credit: [Greg Lindberg](https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-set-a-timeout-in-powershell)